# Codeigniter - custom configuration files loaded depending on machine

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was wondering if there is a way of telling codeigniter to use different autoload/database config when deployed on different machine ?

Aim is to have 2 separate files for config files so it will look something like this:

```
autoload and autoload-server
database and database-server
config and config-server
```

So i can just deploy app to the server and not worry about changing stuff in these files as codeigniter will automatically use ...-server config files and when on dev machine it will use the other files.

Simple flagging could be done via method like that

```
public function determineHost() {
    $addr = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
    $name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    if($addr == "remote ip" || $name == "remote host name") {  
        return "server";
    } 
    if(($addr == "127.0.0.1" || $addr == "::1") || $name == "localhost") {
        return "local";
    }
}
```

and i could have a method which will tell codeigniter to use -server files

```
public function confSelector() {
    if("server"){ 
        use server specific configuration
    } 
    if("local") {
        use local specific configuration
    }
}
```

Any thoughts how i could approach this ? or any solutions

Comment: Looks like you already have it figured out.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @Sparky I am just not sure how to load these config files